# menuitem actionListener is not invoked when form is enclosed in a template

Tags: templates, jsf, primefaces, facelets

When I use a `<p:menuButton>` as follows:

```
<div id="div_menutop">
    <h:form id="form_top">    
        <p:menubar id="mnb_top" >  
            <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon-help">  
                <p:menuitem ajax="true"  process="@this" id="mn_item_help" update="@form" value="Hướng dẫn" actionListener="#{topprocess.helpListener}"/>  
            </p:submenu> 
        </p:menubar>  
        <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{secuser.logout()}" value="Thoát" />
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{topprocess.helpListener}" value="Thoát" />
    </h:form>  
</div>
```

Then it works, the `actionListener` is called.

But when I try to put it in a template composition as follows:

```
<ui:composition>
    <div id="div_menutop">
        <h:form id="form_top">    
            <p:menubar id="mnb_top" >  
                <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon-help">  
                    <p:menuitem id="mn_item_help" update="@form" value="Hướng dẫn" actionListener="#{topprocess.helpListener}"/>  
                </p:submenu> 
            </p:menubar>  
        </h:form>  
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Then the `actionListener` is never called. What can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't nesting forms? (which is illegal in HTML)

Comment: thank you very much, i remove form and it work :)

Comment: Ah nice, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if you're nesting forms. I.e. when the template client has already another `<h:form>`. This is illegal in HTML and the browser behaviour is then unspecified. Some browsers will then send only the data of the outer form, other browsers will send nothing. If JSF hasn't received the parameter name=value of the action, then it won't invoke anything.

You need to remove one of those forms so that they aren't nested anymore.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)